# Multiple authors don't fit on one line

Tags: spacing, titles

I am working with the `article` class.

I have four authors. Unfortunately, they are just a *tiny* bit too wide to fit on one line. (I'm talking less than a quarter inch from the margins I had set.) How can I do one of the two following things:

1. Decrease the space between the authors, just a little bit
2. Make the page temporarily wider around the title

I've tried `\newgeometry`/`\restoregeometry`, but that clears the page at the commands. I've tried `changepage`'s `adjustwidth`, but that makes latex output one extra page at the beginning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify the definition of `\and`; the default is

```
\makeatletter
\def\and{%
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil\relax
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\makeatother
```

Try reducing `1em` to what fits you.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your second question, put the list of authors in a fixed-width box:

```
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{First Author, Second Author, Third Author, Fourth Author}%
```

Without any knowledge of footnotes to author contacts, I think the above should suffice. If you *do* need contact details for authors in a footnote, using `\footnotemark[num]` and `\footnotetext[num]{...}` should do the trick.

The above uses no additional package and doesn't require modification of `LaTeX` internals. However, even though it will remove any unwanted "Overfull `\hbox` warnings", the text will still protrude into both the left and right hand margins. You could also consider using the `letterspacing`, `microtype` or `soul` packages to "fit text into a box."