# Redefining \and spacing in \author

Tags: spacing, titles

How can one redefine the spacing that the `\and` command puts between authors in `\author` within the standard `article` class?  I have a document with three authors whose names are *just* too long to fit on one line with the standard spacing.

I feel like this should probably be doable with a `\setlength` command, but I have no idea what length to set.

For the record, I'm aware of packages like [`authblk`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf) (which I may ultimately use for my purposes), but am more interested in how to modify this spacing directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\and` is in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\makeatletter
\def\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
\makeatother
```

You can redefine it in the preamble by reducing `1em` to whatever fits your needs.

**Note:** The "missing" `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}` and `\end{tabular}` are provided by `\@maketitle`. So any `\author` part is typeset as a tabular.

Comment: Your answer caused [a previous answer of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22914/10906) to appear in the "Related" section for this question, so I've submitted an edit to this answer based on that, further clarifying how to redefine `\and`.